# How to create new JobDetail job in the run time?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am configuring Quartz for client (NOT server) . If i need to create a new `JobDetail job` I would do the following

```
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(TestJob.class)
        .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

        Trigger trigger = . .  

        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Initially I thought I would feed an object of a class to `newJob`.

But the `newJob` method takes a class as an argument (not an instance of a class). `JobBuilder org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob(Class<? extends Job> jobClass)`

I can't create a new class in the run time . This is not efficient at least .

So how can I add new `JobDetail job` in the run time ?

---

Should the `TestJob` class be abstract so that i could customize it in the run time . I'm very confused here

There was a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23506954/how-to-add-job-with-trigger-for-running-quartz-scheduler-instance-without-restar). So it appears " the Quartz scheduler's JobFactory API to load job classes through a custom class-loader and that would allow you to add jobs truly dynamically "

But how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly create `JobDetail` out of an object unless you serialize it (which is not recommended). What you can do is you can create a `HashMap` and add all your data into it and do the following.

```
Map<String, Serializable> jobData = Maps.newHashMap();
        jobData.put("yourkey", "youdata");
        ...
JobDetail job = newJob(TestJob.class).usingJobData(jobData)
      .build();
        //build your trigger
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  But does this mean I'll have to reload all jobs everytime a new job is about to be added

Comment: Wouldnt RMI with codebase be an alternative to handle unknown classes in a quartz scheduler?

Comment: You don't need to reload any existing job to create new job. You are just using the same Job class (`TestJob.class`) which gets called when this particular trigger fires with the jobdetails you provided here. Only job details are dynamic, and the TestJob class's execute method will be called with the dynamic data.

Comment: Also, in general, you don't start (`scheduler.start();`) everytime. This will be done only once.. typically while on start of the application.